# how to get gateway address

Tags: linux, ip, gateway, sles

I am trying to get gateway address but when i call "route -n" I expect to see something like that

```
  Destination     Gateway     Genmask      Flags
  0.0.0.0         dnsip      0.0.0.0         UG     0      0        0 eth0
```

but I only see the flag U ones and gateway ip is 0.0.0.0.

When i look /etc/sysconfig/network/routes i can see the gateway address. I can not use that file because not every versions of open suse have that file. So i need to use a common way to find out the gateway addres.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8
```

Where 8.8.8.8 is an IP address located outside of your network. (In this case is the Google DNS)

Or:

```
ip route list exact 0/0
```